# Generate surrounding numbers, wrap if too large

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, algorithm, math

How can I generate numbers in this way? I want to create a function `generate (current, limit, count)`:

- current – central number in array
- limit – highest number before wrapping
- count - for example, 2 means two numbers before and after current number.

This function might return array like:

```
[ current - n, current - 1, current, current + 1, current + n ] (n <= count)
```

For example:

```
generate(5, 10, 2)
```

Returns:

```
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

But `generate(1, 5, 2)` must return `[4, 5, 1, 2, 3 ]`

Numbers before current take from reverse array of max numbers count.

Comment: Which language, JavaScript or Python? Don't tag both.

Comment: why count, if you got a limit?

Comment: @NinaScholz It looks like `count` tells it when to wrap the values.  Look at the examples.

Comment: This question seems to be technically incorrect. What if i add a pass generate(1,2,10)?

Comment: I swapped the names of `limit` and `count`. It makes more sense this way.

Comment: Here's a Python solution:  `[i % count + 1 for i in range(current - limit - 1, current + limit)]`  This gives the exact results from the examples.

Comment: @SyedMehtabHassan It would need to just keep repeating 1, 2, 1, 2, ...

Comment: Ok, well now you need to reverse `limit` and `count` because of the edit that was made.

Comment: @TomKarzes what if someone pass count < current? generate (5,1,3).

Comment: @SyedMehtabHassan I assume that would be an inconsistent set of parameters, but my solution would simply adjust `count` to be within range.

Answer (score 0):

You could map the values with some adjustments to prevent negative numbers or zero.

```js
function generate(current, limit, count) {
    return Array.from(
        { length: count * 2 + 1 },
        (_, i) => (v => v <= 0 ? v + limit : v)
                  ((current + i - count + limit - 1) % limit + 1)
    );
}

console.log(generate(5, 10, 2).join(' '));  // 3 4 5 6 7
console.log(generate(1, 5, 2).join(' '));   // 4 5 1 2 3
console.log(generate(1, 2, 10).join(' '));  // 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1
```

Answer (score -1):

I think a super simple way you could do this is with a list or array and a for loop.

for the list if you initialize it with the first two numbers you want current-n and current-1 the just use a loop to add in everything else.

myList= [current-n, current-1]

for i in range(current, limit, count):
     myList.append(i)